# Product quick view

Tags: usability

Would you add a product quick view option on hover in the product listing page? Maybe you have any experience with how users respond to such option?

Example can be seen here, where the "quick view" option appears on the product photo:https://vault-bright-demo.mybigcommerce.com/tools-hardware/

(it's a test site)

Comment: Thank you, Reliable Raf & Ameen Akbar!

Answer (score 2):

I might consider which value would bring to your website this kind of feature, and use the most relevant information for the user inside the pop-up.

Personally, I had experienced this pattern using a plug-in for Shopware (CMS). It generated navigation and technical issues. After fixing them, we tested it on production with the real users but unfortunately, we didn´t get a good result in terms of conversion rate. So we decided to remove the plug-in.

There is an article here: https://baymard.com/blog/ecommerce-quick-views

May you find my answer and the article helpful.

Cheers,
Raf

Answer (score 2):

we designed a few versions of quick views for a fashion e-commerce experience, but eventually got rid of it. The numbers and the research revealed that users sometimes use it, but before they bought it they would go to the full product detail view in order to make the decision to buy it. This is true especially for high-priced items like electronics with technical specifications and apparel, where users would check the measurements and size details.

The other common behavior we noticed was where users opened the products they were interested in multiple tabs, then they would go through each of them.